# Python BeautifulSoup selenium scraper

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, tracker

I'm using the following python script for scraping info from Amazon [pages](https://github.com/saiyancode/Basic-Amazon-Rank-Tracker).

At some point, it stopped returning page results. The script is starting, browsing through the keywords/pages but I only get the headers as output:

> Keyword   Rank    Title   ASIN    Score   Reviews Prime   Date

I suspect that the problem is in the following line as this tag doesn't exist anymore and the `results` var doesn't get any value:

`results = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 's-item-container'})`

This is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import datetime
from collections import deque
import logging
import csv


class AmazonScaper(object):

    def __init__(self,keywords, output_file='example.csv',sleep=2):

        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/willcecil/Dropbox/Python/chromedriver')  #Add path to your Chromedriver
        self.keyword_queue = deque(keywords)  #Add the start URL to our list of URLs to crawl
        self.output_file = output_file
        self.sleep = sleep
        self.results = []


    def get_page(self, keyword):
        try:
            self.browser.get('https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords={a}'.format(a=keyword))
            return self.browser.page_source
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(e)
            return

    def get_soup(self, html):
        if html is not None:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
            return soup
        else:
            return

    def get_data(self,soup,keyword):

        try:
            results = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 's-item-container'})
            for a, b in enumerate(results):
                soup = b
                header = soup.find('h2')
                result = a + 1
                title = header.text
                try:
                    link = soup.find('a', attrs={'class': 'a-link-normal a-text-normal'})
                    url = link['href']
                    url = re.sub(r'/ref=.*', '', str(url))
                except:
                    url = "None"

                # Extract the ASIN from the URL - ASIN is the breaking point to filter out if the position is sponsored

                ASIN = re.sub(r'.*amazon.co.uk.*/dp/', '', str(url))

                # Extract Score Data using ASIN number to find the span class

                score = soup.find('span', attrs={'name': ASIN})
                try:
                    score = score.text
                    score = score.strip('\n')
                    score = re.sub(r' .*', '', str(score))
                except:
                    score = "None"

                # Extract Number of Reviews in the same way
                reviews = soup.find('a', href=re.compile(r'.*#customerReviews'))
                try:
                    reviews = reviews.text
                except:
                    reviews = "None"

                # And again for Prime

                PRIME = soup.find('i', attrs={'aria-label': 'Prime'})
                try:
                    PRIME = PRIME.text
                except:
                    PRIME = "None"

                data = {keyword:[keyword,str(result),title,ASIN,score,reviews,PRIME,datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")]}
                self.results.append(data)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        return 1

    def csv_output(self):
        keys = ['Keyword','Rank','Title','ASIN','Score','Reviews','Prime','Date']
        print(self.results)
        with open(self.output_file, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outputfile:
            dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(outputfile, keys)
            dict_writer.writeheader()
            for item in self.results:
                for key,value in item.items():
                    print(".".join(value))
                    outputfile.write(",".join('"' + item + '"' for item in value)+"\n") # Add "" quote character so the CSV accepts commas

    def run_crawler(self):
        while len(self.keyword_queue): #If we have keywords to check
            keyword = self.keyword_queue.popleft() #We grab a keyword from the left of the list
            html = self.get_page(keyword)
            soup = self.get_soup(html)
            time.sleep(self.sleep) # Wait for the specified time
            if soup is not None:  #If we have soup - parse and save data
                self.get_data(soup,keyword)
        self.browser.quit()
        self.csv_output() # Save the object data to csv


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        keywords = [str.replace(line.rstrip('\n'),' ','+') for line in 
    open('keywords.txt')] # Use our file of keywords & replaces spaces with +
    ranker = AmazonScaper(keywords) # Create the object
    ranker.run_crawler() # Run the rank checker
```

The output should look like this (I have trimmed the Titles for clarity).

> Keyword   Rank    Title   ASIN    Score   Reviews Prime   Date
>
> Blue+Skateboard   3   Osprey Complete
>   Beginn    B00IL1JMF4  3.7 40  Prime   February 21, 2019
>   Blue+Skateboard   4   ENKEEO Complete Mini
>   C B078J9Y1DG  4.5 42  Prime   February 21, 2019 Blue+Skateboard   5   skatro -
>   Mini Cruiser  B00K93PIXM  4.8 223 Prime   February 21, 2019
>   Blue+Skateboard   7   Vinsani Retro Cruiser
>     B00CSV72AK  4.4 8   Prime   February 21, 2019 Blue+Skateboard   8   Ridge
>   Retro Cruiser Bo  B00CA33ISQ  4.1 207 Prime   February 21, 2019
>   Blue+Skateboard   9   Xootz Kids Complete
>   Be    B01B2YNSJM  3.6 32  Prime   February 21, 2019 Blue+Skateboard   10  Enuff
>   Pyro II Skateboa  B00MGRGX2Y  4.3 68  Prime   February 21, 2019

Comment: First thing to check is the raw page getting returned. Try inserting `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` before `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')`, and manually check the html to see if the data is there. It is important to do this check on the same machine you are crawling with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following shows some changes you could make. I have changed to using css selectors at some points.

The main result set to loop over are retrieved by `soup.select('.s-result-list [data-asin]')`. This specifies elements with class name `.s-result-list` having children with attribute `data-asin`. This matches the 60 (current) items on page.

I swapped the PRIME selection to using an attribute = value selector

Headers are now `h5` i.e. `header = soup.select_one('h5')`.

---

```
soup.select_one('[aria-label="Amazon Prime"]
```

Example code:

```
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import re

keyword = 'blue+skateboard'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords={}'

driver.get(url.format(keyword))
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
results = soup.select('.s-result-list [data-asin]')

for a, b in enumerate(results):
    soup = b
    header = soup.select_one('h5')
    result = a + 1
    title = header.text.strip()

    try:
        link = soup.select_one('h5 > a')
        url = link['href']
        url = re.sub(r'/ref=.*', '', str(url))
    except:
        url = "None"

    if url !='/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html':
        ASIN = re.sub(r'.*/dp/', '', str(url))
        #print(ASIN)

        try:
            score = soup.select_one('.a-icon-alt')
            score = score.text
            score = score.strip('\n')
            score = re.sub(r' .*', '', str(score))
        except:
            score = "None"

        try:
            reviews = soup.select_one("href*='#customerReviews']")
            reviews = reviews.text.strip()
        except:
            reviews = "None"

        try:
            PRIME = soup.select_one('[aria-label="Amazon Prime"]')
            PRIME = PRIME['aria-label']
        except:
            PRIME = "None"
        data = {keyword:[keyword,str(result),title,ASIN,score,reviews,PRIME,datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")]}
        print(data)
```

---

Example output:

[image]