# Python BeautifulSoup program initialization

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm trying to adjust a Python Scrapy project and run it locally in my PC. The purpose is to study and understand it. I have included start_requests() function in "**main**" but it is not called. Any help or reference to relevant resources, greatly appreciated.

The program compiles without errors, but it just opens a blank browser window. The expected result isto browse through a list of ASIN codes in a .csv and scrape some data from the relevant pages.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
from os.path import splitext, basename

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
#from scrapy import Spider, Request

country_domain = {'US': {'code': 'us', 'domain': 'com'},
                  'UK': {'code': 'uk', 'domain': 'co.uk'},
                  'Germany': {'code': 'de', 'domain': 'de'}, }


def get_asin_url(asin, domain='com'):
#function get_asin_url body emitted for clarity ...    

def get_title(soup):
    title = ""
    pTitle = soup.find('h1', id='title')
    if pTitle:
        title = re.sub('\s+', ' ', pTitle.text.strip())
    return title

class AmazonbotSpider():
    print("I'm in class AmazonbotSpider")
    name = 'amazonbot'
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.*']
    start_urls = ['https://amazon.com/']
    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI': '%(input_filename)s_%(country)s_%(time)s.csv'}

    def __init__(self, asin_path='C:\\Users\\Chris K\Documents\\0_Molzi\\AmazonScraping\\customScripts\\asins.csv', country='UK', *args, **kwargs):
        print("I'm in __init__")
        super(AmazonbotSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.asin_path = asin_path
        self.country = country
        self.country_code = country_domain[country]['domain']
        self.input_filename = splitext(basename(asin_path))[0]

        with open(self.asin_path, 'r') as fp:
            lines = fp.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            asin = line.strip()
            data = get_asin_url(asin, self.country_code)
            #data.meta['item'] = {'asin': asin}
            print("data: ",data)
            #yield data

    def start_requests(self):
        print("I'm in start_requests")
        with open(self.asin_path, 'r') as fp:
            lines = fp.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            asin = line.strip()
            data = Request(get_asin_url(asin, self.country_code), callback=self.parse)
            data.meta['item'] = {'asin': asin}
            print("data: ",data)
            yield data

    def parse(self, response):
        print("I'm in parse")
        item = response.meta['item']
        soup = bs(response.text, 'lxml')
        # Remove any style tags
        style_tags = soup.find_all('style')
        if style_tags:
            for style_tag in style_tags:
                style_tag.extract()
        item['name'] = get_title(soup)
        item['url'] = response.url
        yield item

if __name__ == "__main__":
        spider = AmazonbotSpider() # Create the object
        #spider.start_requests() # Run the rank checker
        print("I'm in __main__")
```

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement in `get_title` in poorly indented.

A linter should help you out writing good python, try out `pylint` for example.

Comment: Yes, as well as this and the `start_requests()` not being indented enough, the line starting `super(AmazonbotSpider, self)...` should be indented to be within the `__init__()` method. Indentation is *very* important in python :)

Comment: Indentation fixed. Thanks for the pylint suggestion. I'm currently using Notepad++. It's early Python days for me. Any ideas why the start_requests() is not called? Also, I cannot figure out what super(AmazonbotSpider, self) does.

Answer (score 0):

You should indent `start_requests()` more - it's currently a function rather than a method within the `AmazonbotSpider` class.

Answer (score 0):

I quit trying to adjust the above code. Instead I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609049/python-beautifulsoup-selenium-scraper) script as a basis and I just added the methods I needed. Using Selenium is the main difference:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import datetime
from collections import deque
import logging
import csv

globaldomain = "es"

class AmazonScaper(object):

    def __init__(self,asins, output_file='results.csv',sleep=2):

        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')  #Add path to your Chromedriver
        self.asin_queue = deque(asins)  #Add the start URL to our list of URLs to crawl
        self.output_file = output_file
        self.sleep = sleep
        self.results = []
    #method body ommited for clarity:
    def get_title(self, soup):
    def get_soldby(self,soup):
    def get_price_seller(self,soup):

    def run_crawler(self):
        price_seller = ""
        while len(self.asin_queue): #If we have asins to check
            asin = self.asin_queue.popleft() #We grab a asin from the left of the list
            html = self.get_page(asin)
            soup = self.get_soup(html)
            time.sleep(self.sleep) # Wait for the specified time
            if soup is not None:  #If we have soup - parse and save data
                title = self.get_title(soup)
                soldby = self.get_soldby(soup)
                price_seller = self.get_price_seller(soup)

                time.sleep(3)
            print(asin,"^^^",title,"^^^",price_seller,"^^^",soldby)
        #self.browser.quit()
        #self.csv_output() # Save the object data to csv

if __name__ == "__main__":
        asins = [str.replace(line.rstrip('\n'),' ','+') for line in open('ASINs.txt')] # Use our file of asins & replaces spaces with +
        ranker = AmazonScaper(asins) # Create the object
        ranker.run_crawler() # Run the rank checker
```